# How to connect two MySQL tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have in my MySqli Database a table called "products".

```
Products TABLE 
product_id       | INT      primary KEY
product_name     | VARCHAR(50)
product_price    | float
```

From PHP i enter rows in the table products like this way:

```
   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO products (product_id,product_name,product_price) VALUES 
                                           ('$product_id','$product_name','$price')");
```

So far all work perfectly. Now i want to have a second table called "category", this table will include all the possible categories that a product can have

The Category table must have a category_id and a category_name as columns

```
Category TABLE 
category_id       | INT      primary KEY
category_name     | VARCHAR(50)
```

I'm trying to figured out a way to connect a product with the category in my PHP file

```
  for example:
  $get=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `category`");
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)) { 
         echo $row['category_name'];   //...here show all the categories
         //...
         //.. pick the category that the product belong
         $category_Selected= .....;
                    }?>
   ..... And make the connection (with INSERT? or something) between product and category
```

Ι want to be able when i'm doing a search at the product table, (for a product X) to show also and the category that it belongs *(so far i can show the Product_id, product_name and product_price)*

Thank you

Comment: you should add  a column category_idid to the table  product for allowe a join between the two tables  or add a table for manage the relation between the two tables

Answer (score 0):

You want to join your Tables.

Take a look here:

[Join Tables - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

[MySQL Join Tables Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: @Tim S thank you for your response. I try with JOIN but with this way i cant make a connection INSERT. table category dont have a ROW "product_id", also with this way (from the tries i made) i cant <<save>> with some way the event that product X belongs to category A and the opposite

Comment: if you want to make an m:n relation you might need a helper table like "product_category_mn" with field product_id and category_id.

have a look here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151904/mapping-many-to-many-relationship

Answer (score 0):

If a product can be only in one category then you can add a category_id in your Products table.

I would suggest a third table the:

```
Product_category
id         | PK
product_id | Foreign key to Products.id
category_id| Foreign key to Categories.id
```

Now every time you insert a product you need to get also the id of your category and do an insert statement to Product_category table.

To retrieve your data you could do something like this:

```
 $get=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `category`");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)) {

      echo $row['category_name'];   //...here show all the categories

      $products=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `Products` WHERE id IN 
      (SELECT product_id from Product_category WHERE category_id= ".(int)$row['category_id'] . ")");

      while ($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($products)) {

           echo $product["product_name"] . ", " . $product["product_price"]; 

      }
    }
```

The above statement is as example, you could use JOIN and prepared statements.

If you choose to alter the product table and add the category_id there, then 
the example code would be this:

```
 $get=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `category`");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)) {

      echo $row['category_name'];   //...here show all the categories
      $products=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `Products` WHERE category_id = " . (int) $row["category_id"]);

      while ($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($products)) {

           echo $product["product_name"] . ", " . $product["product_price"]; 

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is, your database does not allow you to represent the relationshup between categories and products. You would need to alter your design.

I can imagine that one product belongs to a category, and that one category can have several products.

If so, I would recommend creating a `categories` table to store the categories, with (at least) columns `category_id` and `category_name`.

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    category_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    category_name VARCHAR(100)
);
```

In the product table, you want to add a column in the `products` table that stores a reference to the id of the corresponding category :

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD 
    COLUMN category_id INT 
    FOREIGN KEY (category_fk) REFERENCES categories(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

---

With this modified database design, when you insert into `products`, you pass the reference of the category (one could expect that the user of your application will select it from some kind of drop down list when creating the product) :

```
INSERT INTO products (product_id, product_name, product_price, category_id) 
VALUES ( :product_id, :product_name, :price, :category_id );
```

And when you want to display a product along with its category name, you can use a simple JOIN :

```
SELECT p.*, c.category_name
FROM products p
INNER JOIN categories c ON c.category_id = p.category_id
WHERE p.produt_id = :product_id
```

PS : never pass `POST`ed values to your SQL queries like this : this exposes you to SQL injection (and also makes your queries less readable and efficient). I changed the queries to use named parameters.